# Question regarding choosing Cloud Provider

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When creating an account and choose Azure option, does it mean all the services Cloud Services, Query Processing and Database Storage will all be from Azure? Or S3 for Storage and Cloud Services, Query Processing from Azure?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to create a Snowflake account on Azure, then everything related to Snowflake will exist on Azure (Storage, Compute, and Cloud Services) for that account.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[Snowflake as an entire service will use the cloud provider](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-cloud-platforms.html#supported-cloud-platforms) that you choose when creating each account:

> Snowflake is provided as Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) that runs completely on cloud infrastructure.
>
> This means that all three layers of Snowflake’s architecture (storage, compute, and cloud services) are deployed and managed entirely on a selected cloud platform.

However, you can continue to *load* external data from different cloud providers [regardless of the chosen cloud provider](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-cloud-platforms.html#data-loading):

> Snowflake supports loading data from files staged in any of the following locations, regardless of the cloud platform for your Snowflake account:
>
> [...]